# How can I build a std::vector<std::string> and then sort them?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

I have a bunch of strings that I need to sort. I think a std::vector would be the easiest way to do this. However, I've never used vectors before and so would like some help.

I just need to sort them alphanumerically, nothing special. Indeed, the string::compare function would work.

After that, how can I iterate through them to verify that they're sorted?

Here's what I have so far:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), std::string::compare);

for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n", i.c_str);
}
```

Comment: Please see this answer: [boost::sort][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14869307/1038233

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can just do

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

And it will sort your strings. Then go through them checking whether they are in order

```
if(names.empty())
    return true; // empty vector sorted correctly
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i=names.begin(), j=i+1; 
        j != names.end(); 
        ++i, ++j)
    if(*i > *j)
        return false;
return true; // sort verified
```

In particular, `std::string::compare` couldn't be used as a comparator, because it doesn't do what `sort` wants it to do: Return true if the first argument is less than the second, and return false otherwise. If you use `sort` like above, it will just use `operator<`, which will do exactly that (i.e `std::string` makes it return `first.compare(second) < 0`).

Comment: Just for fun (and untested): Checking that the vector is sorted could be simplified to std::adjacent_find(names.begin(), names.end(), std::greater<std::string>()) == names.end()

Answer (score 5):

What is the question exactly? It seems everything is already there.

However, you should probably use `std::cout << *i << std::endl;`

1. `i` is an iterator == pointer to the data in the container, so `*` is needed
2. `c_str()` is a function of `std::string` and not a variable

The problems in your code do not relate to your question?

Some hints for you:

- `std::vector` also overrides `[]` operator, so you can instead save the iterator hassle and use it like an array (iterate from `0` to `vector.size()`).
- You could use `std::set` instead, which has automatically sorting on insertion (binary tree), so you save the extra sorting.
- Using a functor makes your output even more fun: `copy(V.begin(), V.end(), ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, "\n"));`

Answer (score 2):

**For sort use:**
`std::sort`  or `std::vector< std::string>::sort(..)` method.
**To check if it is sorted:**
use `std::is_sorted` for check is sorted -  http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/is_sorted.html
or
`std::adjacent_find( v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater< std::string >() ) == v.end()`

for your case you could use default comparator

**EDITED:**
`std::is_sorted` is not standard stl function, it defined in sgi stl implementation.
Thanks @Brian Neal for this note.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on that sgi site for info on the STL. It predates the standard. is_sorted isn't standard.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong : is_sorted is added in c++11  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted

Answer (score 2):

[litb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688039/how-can-i-build-a-stdvectorstdstring-and-then-sort-them/688068#688068) is correct, as always.

I just wanted to point out the more general point - *anything* that can be compared with < can be sorted with std::sort.  I'll sometimes sneak an operator< member function into a struct, just so I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::set`, which is naturally a sorted container.

Comment: Limitation: std::set doesn't support random access like std::vector.

Comment: std::set doesn't accept duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

***Sorting the string:***

```
using namespace std; // to avoid using std everywhere 
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end()); // this will sort the strings
```

***Checking whether vector is sorted:***

```
if(vec.empty())
    return true; // empty vector is sorted correctly
for(std::vector< std::string>::iterator i=vec.begin(), j=i+1; j != vec.end(); ++i, ++j)
    if(*i > *j)  return false;
return true; // sort verified
```

***C++11 Method to check sorted vector:***
`std::is_sorted(vec.begin(),vec.end())`

***Now printing the sorted vector:***

```
   for(std::vector< std::string>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
{
    std::cout<< *i <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I've checked on codeblocks and ideone and this WORKS just fine.

Comment: Since C++11, checking if the vector is sorted is simply `std::is_sorted(vec.begin(),vec.end())`

Comment: You shouldn't rely on that sgi site for info on the STL. It predates the standard. is_sorted isn't standard

Comment: is_sorted isn't standard

Comment: AFAIK, is_sorted was added in C++11

Answer (score 0):

Try using comparer:

```
// Comparing function only sorts if string size is equal and keeps the larger integgers at last.
bool myFunction (string i, string j) 
{ 
   int n = i.length();
   int m = j.length();

   if (n == m)
       return i < j;
   return n < m;   
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <string> arr(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), mFfunction);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```