# C++ sort array of strings

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of strings, but it's not sorting anything.... what am I doing wrong?

```
string namesS[MAX_NAMES];

int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
    return ( *(char*)a - *(char*)b );
}


void sortNames(){

    qsort(namesS, MAX_NAMES, sizeof(string), compare);
}
```

Comment: Are you considering only the first letter of the strings?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" Using qsort, treating string as a char *...

Comment: Your `compare` function tries to *cast* a `string` to a `char *`. That's definitely not a sane thing to do.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is C++, not C. Sorting an array of strings is easy.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> stringarray;
std::sort(stringarray.begin(), stringarray.end());
```

Comment: Note that you can use `std::sort` on an array too (but `std::vector` is a better idea): `std::sort(namesS, namesS+MAX_NAMES);`

Comment: This is convenient but will not handle case sensitivity. Uppercase W will come before Lowercase a.

Comment: If you want case sensitivity, you need a serious Unicode algorithm and library.

Comment: Not exactly, you can pass a custom compare function or functor to [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and do a case-insensitive comparison there.

Comment: Only if you have a proper Unicode case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 10):

[`std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) is inherited from the standard C library. It will not work.

You need to use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for sorting strings.

Specifically, cast `std::string` to `void*` and then to `char*` is undefined and won't work.

Comment: " It will not work."  It can be made to work.  That's not to say it *should* be made to work.

Comment: @JohnDibling: `qsort` only works with blitable (trivially copyable) types, which `std::string` is not.

Answer (score 8):

algorithm sort in CPP has the same complexity as qsort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool compare(string a, string b){
    cout << "compare(" << a << "," << b << ")" << endl;
    return (a.compare(b) < 0);
}

int main () {

    string mystrs[] = {"www","ggg","bbb","ssss","aaa"};
    vector<string> myvector (mystrs, mystrs + 5);               
    vector<string>::iterator it;

  sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), compare);

  cout << "vector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This contained an example initialization of vector<string>, not just an example declaration!  Thank you, better than accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use boost::sort, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> stringarray;
boost::sort(stringarray);
```

If you want use find use boost::find, like this:

```
std::string findme;
auto offset = boost::find(stringarray, findme) - stringarray.begin()
```

See 2 useful functions (m_stringarray should be member of ClassA):

```
const size_t ClassA::GetIdByName(std::string name) const
{
    return (boost::find(this->m_stringarray, name) - this->m_stringarray.begin());
}

const std::string ClassA::GetNameById(size_t id) const
{
    return this->m_stringarray[id];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As many here have stated, you could use std::sort to sort, but what is going to happen when you, for instance, want to sort from z-a? This code may be useful

```
bool cmp(string a, string b)
{
if(a.compare(b) > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
string words[] = {"this", "a", "test", "is"};
int length = sizeof(words) / sizeof(string);
sort(words, words + length, cmp);

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cout << words[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
    // output will be: this test is a 

}
```

If you want to reverse the order of sorting just modify the sign in the cmp function.

Comment: The body of `cmp` can be just `return a < b;`, which is also easy to reverse.  One can also avoid implementing a custom `cmp` and just pass either `std::less<std::string>()` or `std::greater<std::string>()` to `std::sort`

Answer (score 0):

> Here is **C++** another way to sort array of string without using ***<vector>***.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string WordArray[] = {"AA","DD","CC","BB","ZZ","NN"};
    sort(begin(WordArray), end(WordArray));  /*Sort the Array*/
    for(auto& Word: WordArray){
       cout<<Word<<endl;                     /*Print Every String Element*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```