# Sorting string array alphabetically in a 2D array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have coded thus far and I am not sure how to sort using the 2-dimensional array. Basically, one function is for sorting an array of strings, another function is for swapping two strings. Any help would be appreciated. (Also I am not allowed to use c++ 11 :/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

void input_name(string&);
void sort_names(string&);
void repeat_pro(int&);
void sortArray(string, int);
int main() {

    string b_list[100][2];                                              
    string name;
    int choice;
    int count=0;

    cout << "Welcome to the Business Sorting Program!" << endl;
    do{
        input_name(name);
        b_list[count][1] = name;      
        count++; 
        repeat_pro(choice);
        cout<<"\n \n Your Businesses are:"<<endl;
            for(int j=0; j<count; j++){
                cout<<b_list[j][1]<<endl;  
            }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }while(choice == 0);
    cout << "Thanks for using this program"<<endl;


    return 0;
}


void input_name(string &name){
    cout << "Enter in the name of the business: ";
    getline(cin, name);
}

void sort_names(string &name){

}

void repeat_pro(int &choice){
  cout << "Do you want to enter in more names: ";
  string answ;
  cin>>answ;
  cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
  if (answ == "YES" || answ == "Y" || answ == "yes" || answ == "y"){
      choice = 0;
  }
  else {
      choice = 1;
  }
  }
```

Comment: C++03 has `std::sort`. It also has `std::vector`. Better avoid raw arrays.

Comment: Why the 2d array? If you have a pair of items use a pair, or a struct to group them. Especially difficult to tell why since your example doesn't use both. Which one is the key to sort on? IMO struct is easier to manage than pair, but either is workable.

Comment: I have to use arrays since my instructor asked me to. I was thinking about using the second row of it to place them in order. But I am not sure how to do it with strings

Comment: If you don't need the 2d array there's plenty of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803071/c-sort-array-of-strings

Comment: I haven;t seen any ```b_list[x][0]```, are you even refering to your 1st column of your 2 dimensional array?

Comment: you could [sort the indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580982/c-sort-keeping-track-of-indices) and then recreate each row of the original array in the order of the sorted indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not clear to me from the description what problem the program really tried to solve. I'm assuming it's kind of like a two column spreadsheet, the second column is the name entered by the user(but what is in the first column?).

assume you need to keep the array in sorted order as the data goes in, just do a binary search (you can do a linear search for small dataset like 100 entries).

```
// we don't have lambda before C++11
struct comparator {
  bool operator () (const string (&x)[2], const string (&y)[2]) const {
    return x[1] < y[1];
  }
};

//... omitted

string data[100][2];
int count = 0;
while (count < 100) {
    // no rvalue, move, rvo, etc. before C++11
    string name;
    input_name(name);
    // no type deduction and lambda
    string (*position)[2] =
            std::lower_bound(&data[0], &data[count], name, comparator());
    int index = position - &data[0];
    // simulate an vector::insert operation, but for our array
    for (int i = count; i > index; --i) {
        // before we had move in C++, we would do swap with an empty element.
        // in this case, the entry at data[count] is default constructed
        std::swap(data[i][1], data[i-1][1]);
    }
    data[index][1] = name;
}
//... omitted
```

of course we can use a typedef to make it cleaner, but that's left to you.